# React useEffect warnings and recursive loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-redux

I have two issues in the code below and I need inputs from the community for the same.

1. I am getting a `React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'medicationState.eligibilityResponse'. Either include it or remove the dependency array warning` warning but when I include `medicationState.EligibilityResponse` in the `useEffect()` array below(instead of `showBadge`) then the component goes into a recursive infinite loop.
2. Also the medication is showing as eligible always(i.e `showBadge` is set as true) even though the endpoint is returning false.

Would the community have an input on these issues?

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { GroupMed } from '../../../../state/ducks/medications/models';
import { medicationsActions } from '../../../../state/ducks/medications';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { ApplicationState } from '../../../../state/ducks';
import {
    ChaseJSON,
    ExMedJSON,
    FetchEligibilityRequest,
    PrescriptionJSON,
} from '../../../../state/ducks/medications/types';
import { MedicationStatusProps } from './v2-recipes/medication-status';

export interface MedicationBadgeProps {
    index: number;
    groupMed: GroupMed;
}

const MedicationBadge: React.FC<MedicationStatusProps> = ({ index, groupMed }: MedicationBadgeProps) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const medicationState = useSelector((state: ApplicationState) => state.medicationState);
    let showBadge = false;
    useEffect(() => {
        if (!(medicationState.EligibilityResponse && medicationState.EligibilityResponse.data)) {
            const groupMedItem = groupMed.groupMedItems[0];
            const fetchEligibilityRequest: FetchEligibilityRequest = {
                rxcui: groupMedItem.getRxcui(),
                groupMedItemType: groupMedItem.item.groupMedItemType,
                groupMedItemDrug:
                    (groupMedItem.item as ChaseJSON).drug ||
                    (groupMedItem.item as PrescriptionJSON).drug ||
                    (groupMedItem.item as ExMedJSON).externalMed.drug,
                medicationSearchResult:
                    (groupMedItem.item as ChaseJSON).searchResult ||
                    (groupMedItem.item as ExMedJSON).externalMed?.healthProfileMedication?.searchResult,
            };
            dispatch(
                medicationsActions.fetchEligibility(groupMedItem.getId(), fetchEligibilityRequest),
            );
        }
    }, [dispatch, showBadge, groupMed.groupMedItems]);
    if (medicationState.EligibilityResponse.data?.isEligible) {
        showBadge = medicationState.EligibilityResponse.data?.isEligible;
    }
    if (showBadge) {
        return (
            <ui-section flowDirection="horizontal" spacingTop="mini">
                <ui-icon imgClass="eligible" spacingRight="mini" style={{ marginLeft: '0px' }}></ui-icon>
            </ui-section>
        );
    } else {
        return <></>;
    }
};

export default MedicationBadge;
```

Answer (score 0):

Functions like `dispatch` and `setState` is handled by React itself and is stable, so you don't need to include it as dep. As to `showBadge`, there's no where to be seen it's usage inside the effect callback, so you probably don't need it. `medicationState.eligibilityResponse` should be included.

Modified as follows (assume `medicationsActions` is a collection of stable actions):

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (!medicationState.EligibilityResponse?.data) { // optional chainning using ?
    const groupMedItem = groupMed.groupMedItems[0];

    const fetchEligibilityRequest: FetchEligibilityRequest = {
      rxcui: groupMedItem.getRxcui(),
      groupMedItemType: groupMedItem.item.groupMedItemType,
      groupMedItemDrug:
        (groupMedItem.item as ChaseJSON).drug ||
        (groupMedItem.item as PrescriptionJSON).drug ||
        (groupMedItem.item as ExMedJSON).externalMed.drug,
      medicationSearchResult:
        (groupMedItem.item as ChaseJSON).searchResult ||
        (groupMedItem.item as ExMedJSON).externalMed?.healthProfileMedication
          ?.searchResult,
    };

    dispatch(
      medicationsActions.fetchEligibility(
        groupMedItem.getId(),
        fetchEligibilityRequest
      )
    );
  }
}, [groupMed.groupMedItems, medicationState.EligibilityResponse]);
```

If the loop keeps appearing, I'd double check the if condition is correct.

Comment: Thank you @enfield Li, for your input. If I make the above changes, the application goes into an infinite loop. Also how would I set the `showBadge` variable based on the `medicationState.rxPassMedEligibilityResponse.data?.isEligible`?  I will look more into this to ensure that the variable is actually getting set.

Comment: I suspect `medicationState.EligibilityResponse` remains to be a falsy value after the dispatch, and that's causing the loop, try log it above the `useEffect`, and see the value